# Ignore results that are empty or null in count

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am getting a list of web elements and then counting how many items are found. Say there are a total of 10 fields found, but only 4 contain information. How would I ignore the null and/or empty results when getting the size?

```
//Get link fields
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a"));

//Print out how many fields are found
System.out.println("Link text = " + Integer.toString(elements.size()));
```

Comment: What do you mean by "contain information"? Can you give an example?

Comment: @Jose answered my question, but say I'm doing a search for all the <a> elements that have an id associated with it (like .getAttribute("id")), not all the <a> tags have an id, but some do, therefore, I was getting some blank results. I wanted to only return results that had info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to count them.

```
//Get link fields
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a"));

// Count fields with information
int count = 0;
for ( WebElement e : elements ) {
  if ( e!=null && containsInformation(e) )
    ++count;
}

//Print out how many fields are found
System.out.println("Link text = " + count );
```

containsInformation is up to you. Depending on your context it could be `e.isEnabled()`, `e.isSelected()` or something entirely different.

Also, you don't need Integer.toString to concatenate an integer to a string.

Comment: Thank you sir! You pointed me in the right direction. Here's what I ended up doing:


`//Get link fields
List<WebElement> elements7 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a"));

//Count fields with information
int count = 0;
for ( WebElement e : elements7 ) {
 int length = e.getAttribute("title").length();
if ( length > 0 )
 ++count;
}
System.out.println("Link text count = " + count);`